# cross-reboot monotonic systemd timer

Tags: cron, systemd, reboot

The timer functionality of systemd includes *monotonic timers*, which measure time in real uptime since some starting point *after boot*. This means that after a boot, the service triggered by the timer is started and then the timer fires according to some predefined conditions based on actual uptime, i.e., excluding suspend episodes.

Is it possible to have a monotonic timer that not only crosses suspend episodes, but also actual downtime, so crosses reboots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently this is not possible. A feature request has been filed: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3107